# VB6 check to se if zip is empty after execute a code

Tags: vb6

This is the code i have, after execution it starts to delete unmatched items from treeview2.
if some zip files does not contain matched files than the contents of zip file gets deleted but zip remains with the size of 1k and its empty.

Instead of leaving the dead empty zip can i rather move the zip to newly created folder in the zip path and leave the contents as it is and move on.

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()
Dim objNode1 As Node
Dim objNode2 As Node
Dim objMatchNode As Node
Dim objChildNode1 As Node
Dim objChildNode2 As Node
Dim iCounter1 As Integer
Dim iCounter2 As Integer
Dim fFound As Boolean

On Error Resume Next

For Each objNode1 In TreeView2.Nodes

    ' Find matching node in Treeview2
    For Each objNode2 In TreeView1.Nodes
        If objNode2.Text = objNode1.Text Then
            ' Match found
            Set objMatchNode = objNode2
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not objMatchNode Is Nothing Then

        ' Check all children
        If objNode1.Children > 0 Then

            ' Get first Child
            Set objChildNode1 = objNode1.Child

            ' Loop through all children
            For iCounter1 = 1 To objNode1.Children

                'If objChildNode1.Image = 3 And objNode1.Image = 9 Then

                    ' Check if it already exists in Treeview2
                    If objMatchNode.Children > 0 Then

                        ' Get first Child
                        Set objChildNode2 = objMatchNode.Child

                        ' Set Found flag to False
                        fFound = False

                        ' Loop through all children
                        For iCounter2 = 1 To objMatchNode.Children

                            ' Check for match
                            If objChildNode2.Text = objChildNode1.Text Then
                                fFound = True
                                Exit For
                            End If

                            ' Get next node
                            Set objChildNode2 = objChildNode2.Next
DoEvents
                        Next

                        If fFound Then
                            ' Add to Treeview2
                            'TreeView2.Nodes.Add objMatchNode.Key, tvwChild, objChildNode1.Key, objChildNode1.Text, 3
             Else
DeleteFileFromArchive objChildNode1.Text, "C:\Users\sarah\Desktop\rom test\" & objNode2.Text




                        End If

                    End If

               ' End If

                ' Get next node
                Set objChildNode1 = objChildNode1.Next
DoEvents

            Next

        End If


    End If

Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will find the nodes that are empty and delete them. You can add code to delete the actual Zip file in here, where it says "Delete Zip":

```
Private Sub DeleteFromTreeView(ByRef p_objTreeView As TreeView)
    Dim objNode As Node
    Dim fDelete As Boolean
    Dim iDeleteIndex As Integer
    Dim sDeleteName As String

    ' Get first node from TreeView
    Set objNode = p_objTreeView.Nodes(1)

    Do While Not objNode Is Nothing

        ' Set Delete flag to false
        fDelete = False

        ' Check if node has children, otherwise delete file
        If objNode.Children = 0 Then
            fDelete = True
            iDeleteIndex = objNode.Index
            sDeleteName = objNode.Text
        End If

        ' Go to next sibling
        Set objNode = GetNextSibling(p_objTreeView, objNode)

        If fDelete Then
            ' Delete Zip
            p_objTreeView.Nodes.Remove iDeleteIndex
        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

You can run this code on your TreeView after your existing code. The `sDeleteName` will contain the name of the Zip you want to delete, just add some code to delete the file using something like this:

```
Sub DeleteFile(p_sFilePath)
    Dim objFSO As New FileSystemObject
    If objFSO.FileExists(p_sFilePath) Then objFSO.DeleteFile p_sFilePath
End Sub
```

This Sub uses the FileSystemObject so make sure you add a reference to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** in your project.

You will also need the following Helper functions you might already have in your project:

```
Function GetNextSibling(ByRef p_objTreeView As TreeView, ByRef p_objNode As Node) As Node
    If HasSibling(p_objTreeView, p_objNode) Then
        Set GetNextSibling = p_objTreeView.Nodes(GetNextSiblingIndex(p_objNode))
    Else
        Set GetNextSibling = Nothing
    End If
End Function

Function HasSibling(ByRef p_objTreeView As TreeView, ByRef p_objNode As Node) As Boolean
    HasSibling = Not (p_objNode.LastSibling Is p_objNode)
End Function

Function GetNextSiblingIndex(ByRef p_objNode As Node) As Integer
    With p_objNode
        GetNextSiblingIndex = .Index + .Children + 1
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: does treeview has filter ? so if image index =4 then send all image index = 4 to top of the list ?